# Are books on mathematics related topics for computer science from 20+ years ago still relevant?

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I am planning to take a computer science degree soon. I have found that topics such as discrete mathematics and probability & statistics are included in their syllabus. I wanted to read books on these topics to prep myself before going into it.

However, many of those books are published 10-20 years ago, and i was wondering if they would still be relevant for the current applications in computer science?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes. The mathematics and even the theoretical computer science don't change as rapidly as the specific hardware and software you use. Even a good book on programming is still relevant.

Comment: Things like introductory discrete mathematics, mathematical logic, linear algebra and probability have not changed much, which others such as machine learning and applied statistics have changed substantially (largely due to the availability of greater computer power)

Comment: In fact, there were quite a few books variously titled *Finite Mathematics*, *Computer Mathematics*, etc. published in the 1960s and 1970s that cover the topics you mentioned  and which are perfectly fine, with the possible exception of chapters on things like "switching circuits" and the like that were perhaps more fundamental in the curriculum than is the case now.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answer!

Comment: There are certain things you will find in older books that are not nearly as relevant today as they were in the past. When I studied Numerical Analysis in the 1980's, computational complexity of an algorithm was measured by "FLOPS" - floating point operations - which then meant multiplications and divisions. At that time addition and subtraction were so much faster than multiplication and division, their contribution to runtime was considered negligible. But the much-more complex chips of today can handle all four operations just as fast, so this is no longer true.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair Can I assume that this is true mostly for the theory/application part only, but the raw calculation methods would still be relevant?

Comment: Math is all "theory/application", so there is no "only". The algorithms still work, but which algorithms work best - produce the greatest accuracy in the least amount of time - has changed. And new algorithms have been created that will not be included in the older books. Old books will give you, say 90-95%, of what you need to know for computation. But for the other 5-10%, you will need to look at more recent stuff.

Comment: Alright understood, thank you so much!